# Использование std::move для тривиального типа

Tags: c++, c++11, конструктор

Встретил такой конструктор:

```
MyClass(SomeType value) noexcept :
    m_value { std::move(value) }
{}
```

При этом `SomeClass` - это какой-то тривиальный (встроенный) тип, собственно, поскольку его экземпляр небольшой по размеру, он и передается по значению, а зачем еще `std::move` использовать? Неужели предполагается какая-то оптимизация или повышение эффективности при использовании перемещения для тривиального типа?

Comment: Может это из какого-то шаблонного кода перекочевало.

Comment: @alexout да, полагаю, именно так.

Comment: Вот если в будущем понадобится использовать в качестве `SomeType` какой-нибудь не встроенный тип, то понадобится меньше рефакторинга.

Comment: @VTT а на текущем уровне (работа со встр. типом) мы не получим накладных расходов? Ведь перемещение для int не имеет особого преимущества перед копированием, а тут еще и move привлекается. Или мы как обычно уповаем на оптимизацию компилятора?

Comment: @VTT а если будет нетривиальный тип, то придется переоформить под perfect forwarding - это лучше, ведь ожидаем что объект уже хуже копируется

Comment: Для примитивных типов перемещения как такового нет, есть только копирование, так что в плане оптимизации для них нет никакой выгоды.